# How can I remove a folder called "..."?

Tags: windows-10, window

I have accidentally created a folder in Windows called "`...`" (the typescript compiler generated it because of a wrong configuration) and now I cannot remove this folder.

I have tried removing the folder via the explorer (the explorer crashed) and also via command line (`del`/`rmdir`). A restart didn't help either.

How can I remove this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Command Prompt and type

```
RD ...\
```

Don't miss the last backslash, it's critical. Otherwise CMD will only complain `A subdirectory or file ...... already exists.`

You can also create it again:

```
MD ...\
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use IObit Unlocker tool to unlock and delete some file or folder. It is easier. You could use it to delete it.
[image]

Comment: That's the exact tool I'm using, too.